# Similar To vs. ILike in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

If I want to capture all Descriptions that have "Dillard s" (with the space being any single alphanumeric wildcard), is it more appropriate to use:

```
DESCRIPTION iLIKE '%Dillard_s%'
```

or use

```
DESCRIPTION Similar To '%Dillard_s%'
```

Thanks!

Comment: What does "more appropriate" here mean? Are you wondering if there is a difference in the results returned, the performance, or what?

Comment: Does one work and the other not?

Comment: Seems like that would be pretty easy to test. The manual on postgresql.org is pretty detailed too. (I'd link to the page, but I'm on mobile.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `like`:

```
DESCRIPTION LIKE '%Dillard_s%'
```

If you don't want case-insensitivity (and your question suggests you don't), then just use `like`.

I tend to use either `LIKE` or go whole-hog and use regular expressions:

```
DESCRIPTION ~ 'Dillard[a-zA-Z0-9]s%'
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff.  In case I want case sensitivity, would this suffice: DESCRIPTION iLIKE '%Dillard_s%'

Comment: @ZJAY . . . Yes.  `ilike` does exactly that.